# Convert Time Format AM/PM to 24 hour

Tags: vb.net, time

I have a large amount of data importing into excel and the current format of the time is:

```
12:30pm    Value1
5:00pm     Value2
5:00am     Value3
```

which I need to convert into 24 hour format and then sort in order:

```
05:00      Value3
12:30      Value1
17:00      Value2
```

I can sort the data but i cant work out how to convert the time format.
Its important to note that once this has been run ill be exporting to the time value to a text file so just formatting the column doesn't work.

Any help would be great thanks.

Edit: (What I have tried)

```
Dim FSTs As String = FSTimeM.Value
            Dim Hour24Time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(FSTs)
            xlsApp.ActiveCell.Value = Hour24Time.ToString("HH:mm")
```

The FSTimeM is coming from a Regex Match.
This method gives the correct results if the excel column is formatted to time but when i export this value to another program it comes through as a decimal number.

Comment: can you please share your efforts ?

Comment: Edited above, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
xlsApp.ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
```

before you set the value of the cell, to set the cell format to text.

Note that you need to format the cell before you set the value, so it's stored in the cell as text, instead of as a date.

Comment: Thank a lot, it worked! Its weird because the column was already formatted to text but hey ho, Thanks for your time